# Read data from JPanel inside JDialog before close

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, dispose, jdialog

I have to display a Jpanel inside a JDialog and so far I dealt with it however I don't know how to close the dialog and receive the data inside the Jpanel before disposing of it.

```
    newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
             JDialog dialog = new JDialog(Main.getMainFrame(), true);
            JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
            dialog.getContentPane().add(jPanel);
            dialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 800));
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            if (jPanel.close)
            {
                /*read some useful information from the jpanel*/
                dialog.setVisible(false);
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        }
    });
```

so far I have put a button inside the Jpanel which sets a boolean close = true and the dialog reads it and disposes of itself. However this doesn't work: I suspect the `jPanel.close()` is tested before I click close inside the JPanel while it should wait for the actual close value to change.

Comment: Show us the code you are using for the button.  Also, you might like to take a look [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features)

Comment: the button inside JPanel is a simple:     private void closeJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                            
    {                                                
        close = true;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like this to get container window instance (`JDialog` in our case)

```
JDialog parentDialog=(JDialog)SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(jPanel);
```

Comment: Thank you.. I used the getWindowAncestor method and correctly closed the parent dialog.